# share data between views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing application using Ionic Framework and there's problem I can't solve.
I have few views that are steps and must share data, user can also step back, go to some else views and come back later. His input should be stored until last step is finished then I can persist model and I need new empty one.

I used factory for this, but I can't find a way to clear object that is returned. Is it possible?
What's some other approaches that I can use here?

app.js

```
.state('topup', {
url: "/topup",
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup.html",
controller:'TopupCtrl'
})

.state('topup-1', {
url: "/topup-1",
templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup-1.html",
controller:'TopupCtrl'
})

.state('topup-2', {
url: "/topup-2",
templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup-2.html",
controller:'TopupCtrl'
})
```

controllers.js

```
.controller('TopupCtrl', function($scope, $state, TopupData, HistoryData) {
$scope.data = TopupData.getCurrent();
$scope.selectOperator = function(operator) {
    $scope.data.Operator = operator;
    $state.go("topup-2");
};
$scope.acceptTopup = function(){
    HistoryData.getHistory().push($scope.data);
    console.log(HistoryData.getHistory());
    TopupData.setCurrent({});
    $state.go("main");
};
})
```

services.js

```
.factory('TopupData', function () {
var service = {};
var Model = {};
service.setCurrent = function(value)
{
Model = value;
};
service.getCurrent = function(value)
{
return Model;
};

return service;
})
```

Comment: why you use same controller in all states

Comment: It seems sufficient, there's more steps that use simple functions like these above that use only TopupData, so is there any reason to split it on multiple controllers?

Comment: you why you don't just wrap it on `ui-view` parent div and remove the controller from state Level

Comment: Thanks, good advice. I'm quite novice with angular.js and these are my first steps with Ionic.

Comment: re initializing controller for no reason on state change is not good thing

Comment: take a look at my answer which i added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
console.log(HistoryData.getHistory());
var resetObj = {};
TopupData.setCurrent(resetObj);
$state.go("main");
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to pinpoint the problem. It cleared the object, but controller wasn't reloaded and used old object from scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to don't define a controller on state level, if they are of the same name, re initializing same controller on state change is not good idea.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TopupCtrl">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

**CODE**

```
.state('topup', {
    url: "/topup",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup.html"
})

.state('topup-1', {
    url: "/topup-1",
    templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup-1.html"
})

.state('topup-2', {
    url: "/topup-2",
    templateUrl: "templates/topup/topup-2.html"
})
```

Then i don't think so you will need factory anymore, as there no need to share a scope.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to refactor it to not reinitialize controller on state change. Ionic uses http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ instead ui-view, but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing code like this, solved my problem:

```
    var resetObj = {};
    TopupData.setCurrent(resetObj);
    $state.go("main").then(function(){
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    });
```